# Recording Microsoft Edge using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, microsoft-edge

I am trying to record my company intranet site using Edge browser through JMeter 5.1.1. JMeter seems to be working fine with Firefox and Chrome, but not with Edge.

I am getting "Go to proxy settings" error message when I try to access the home page. It's working fine in my personal laptop, but not in my company machine. Is there anything do with firewall to record https traffic in Edge?

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In my case it saying error_connecting_proxy_server. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case your company uses a corporate proxy so you need to [make JMeter aware of this proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)

Also given you can record using any other browser you can make JMeter to "pretend" being Edge by manipulating [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/)

The relevant User-Agent string for Microsoft Edge 44.17763.831.0 would be

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763
```

You can get your own Edge User-Agent string from [Edge developer tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Dmitri. There is no corporate proxy in our company. We have not been provided any proxy or port number. Could it be any other reason for this recording issue??

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Edge browser are you using? From [this article](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and [this blog](https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/26/jmeter-recording/#firefox-setup), it seems that when using JMeter to recording, you have to configure your browser to use the JMeter Proxy.

To set up a proxy in the Legacy version of Edge browser, please check the following steps:

1. Launch **Edge** from your Start menu, desktop or taskbar.
2. Click the **More** button in the top-right corner of the window. (It looks like three dots.)
3. Click **Settings**.
4. Click **Advanced** settings. You might have to scroll down a bit to find it.
5. Click **Open proxy settings**.
6. Click the switch beneath **Use a proxy server** to turn it on.
7. Type the IP address of the proxy server you're using, which should be provided to you by the proxy service.
   Type the port number. Again, this number should be provided to you by the proxy service.

   [image]
8. Click Save.

To set up a proxy in the New Microsoft Edge, you could use the following steps:

1. Launch **Edge** from your Start menu, desktop or taskbar.
2. Click the **More** button in the top-right corner of the window. (It looks like three dots.)
3. Click **Settings**.
4. Click the **System**, and then click the **Open your computer's proxy settings**.

   [image]
5. Click the switch beneath **Use a proxy server** to turn it on.
6. Type the IP address of the proxy server you're using, which should be provided to you by the proxy service.
   Type the port number. Again, this number should be provided to you by the proxy service.
7. Click **Save** button

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Zhi Lv. I have followed the same steps as you mentioned here. Still I am getting the same error "Go to Proxy settings". It's working fine in my personal laptop. But not in my company machine. Is there anything do with firewall to record https traffic in Edge? Updated my query too.

Comment: To the firewall, please make sure the related port is Allow status.

Comment: Added the port (which we will use in JMeter recorder) in Windows firewall defender inbound rules. Able to record the common websites but not my intranet sites. Any other settings needs to be done?